# Remove iOS 5.1 notification from the main screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, software-update

I do not want to update my iPhone 3gs to new iOS 5.1. How can I remove this notification showing all the time on the `Settings` images. Please look at the image.

[image]

I've tried opening this screen but without clicking the button Download and Install, but the notification is still there.

PS. I am new to iPhone. I have it for a couple of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that your iPhone is jailbroken. There's a tweak for this called [noOTA badge](http://www.techow.net/how-to-remove-the-settings-app-badge-from-a-jailbroken-iphone-or-ipad). I haven't used it myself, but it looks legit. Give it a shot!

Comment: use NoOTA Badge from cydia It is the best tweak to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

From [Macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=617096):

> Uncheck it from your iTunes so that is won't resync it, and then
>   delete it from the phone. Then it won't be on the phone anymore but
>   will still be in your iTunes for later use if you want it back.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. Did you mean iTunes app or App Store app?

Comment: I thought deleting the Settings app was impossible.

Comment: It is. But I think Macrumors is referring to the update, not the Settings app